# Found a bug - regarding inserting modified data via browser into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, firefox, firebug

I created select option list and added some data.

```
    <select disabled  readonly="readonly">
    <option>Something</option>
    <option>Something</option>
    </select>
```

But in firefox when i inspect element and change value of option list via firebug extension i can update or insert into database that value. How do you solve this kind of problems ?

Comment: You need to prevent this from server side back in php

Comment: Could you please provide some link regarding this problem ?

Comment: You should match or validate value using php.

Comment: Front end validation is good for usability, but does little for security. You still need to do backend validation.

Comment: only php backend validation and that is not a bug!

Answer (score -1):

Use the option value attribute, then use AJAX to retrieve the value and send it to the server. Like this--> `document.getElementById("select-me").value;`

```
<select disabled  readonly="readonly" id="select-me">
<option value="A">Something1</option>
<option value="B">Something2</option>
</select>
```

**SERVER SIDE**:

```
$choice = $_POST["choice"];

switch ($choice){
    case "A":
    $option = "Something1"
    break;
    case "B":
    $option = "Something2"
    break;
    default:
      $option = "no choice selected"
    break;


}
```

Comment: I belive, you misunderstood this question. It is about how to validate data sent from the client.

Comment: Yes. this is how you validate data sent from the client. The question was tagged with PHP so I assumed the OP wanted some sort of server validation.